# neo4j: discover data structure

Tags: neo4j

I am getting started with cypher queries.  Before being able to query I need to know about the data structure

When working with a new database how do you discover its model
what properties do nodes have
what are the relationships and their properties
what are the indexes, what properties are indexed

can this be done with cypher queries?

Answer (score 2):

I typically do a few queries like:

```
start n=node(*)
match n-[r?]-m
return *
skip 0
limit 100;
```

http://console.neo4j.org/r/rynad7

If you have a lot of data you can increase your skip value to see more.

Comment: Thanks,  here is a way to find indexes that I have puzzled out in embedded  mode   IndexManager im = graphDb.index()
println "node indexes are"
println im.nodeIndexNames()
// how to find out what properties are indexed?

println "relationship indexes are"
println im.relationshipIndexNames()